# This Ajax javascript code not working right

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, jquery

So I have been busy building a site for a customer. Now I need to do some ajax on menu clicks. The code below is successful in showing the loading.gif and not 100% sure it does the ajax as the dang page still loads up regular style with the gif spinning. Works but doesn't..

Anyways heres a link to it:  and login is
username: 
password:

Click on "Friends" Link to see the spinner and the code below is viewable via firebug. Any help here is good help, this is actually my first time messing with ajax.

Thanks,
Nick

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$(".item-206").click(function() {
    $("#dvloader").show();
    $.load("friends", function(){ $("#dvloader").hide(); });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: That page just gives me a `403 Forbidden` error and doesn't ask for credentials.

Comment: it works just don't understand why without http or www in front of it it doesn't, ill figure that out

Comment: @Binary101010 Link fixed.  It doesn't work because you likely haven't done the url rewrite rules in htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell it where to load the html into:

```
$('#div-you-want-to-populate').load("friends", function() { ... });
```

If you make an array of div ids, and name them the same as the target divs, you can do:

```
var ids = ['id1', 'id2','id3']; 
for (i=0; i<ids.length, i++) { 
    $('#'+ids[i]).load("friends #"+ids[i], function() { ... });
};
```

Comment: Ok hey thks, I actually removed that code earlier, though that was the load specific div from remote file.

Comment: I have one more question.. I guess I don't want to load the whole page, I actually just want to load specific divs into specific divs from the friends page. What Am I missing bud

Comment: edit: just realized it was dumb to put code in here, edited answer instead

Comment: give me a second I have to look at what you have on that page

Comment: Oh I mean notice when u click friends(menu item) it loads your profile into the page menu items are all the links in the navigation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28282/discussion-between-binary101010-and-dave)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$('element or id or class').load("friends", function(){ $("#dvloader").hide(); });
```